# Calculate singular vectors from singluar values

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to find a way to calculate the left and right singluar vectors from a complex 2x2 Matrix and its singular values.

Expanding the matrix product of the svd leads to 4 equations with 8 unkowns and I don't know a way to include the side condition that the matrices that are formed by the singluar vectors are unitary.

Comment: Not sure. Decomposing the matrix into eigenvectors and singluar vectors using Matlab's svd and eig function leads to different solutions.

Answer (score 2):

To find the left singular vectors of $\mathbf{A}$, find the eigenvectors of $\mathbf{AA}^\mathrm{H}$. Likewise, for the right singular vectors, find the eigenvectors of $\mathbf{A}^\mathrm{H}\mathbf{A}$. The fact that $\mathbf{A}\in\mathbb{C}^{2\times 2}$ rather than $\mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$ should not affect the process.

To see the above note that if $\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{USV}^\mathrm{H}$, then

$$
\mathbf{AA}^\mathrm{H} = \left(\mathbf{USV}^\mathrm{H}\right) \left(\mathbf{USV}^\mathrm{H}\right)^\mathrm{H} = \mathbf{USS}^\mathrm{H}\mathbf{U}^\mathrm{H},
$$

which is an eigendecomposition. A similar result holds for $\mathbf{A}^\mathrm{H}\mathbf{A}$.